# Match against List and pil

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am new to pil package. I wish to merge only those images whose name is in the list.

w.txt file contains these filename

```
1
2
```

Folder contains 4 images 1.png, 2.png, 3.png and 4.png

```
from PIL import Image

with open('w.txt') as f:
    my_list =list(f)
    print(my_list)

img_01 = Image.open("1.png")
img_02 = Image.open("2.png")
img_03 = Image.open("3.png")
img_04 = Image.open("4.png")

img_01_size = img_01.size
img_02_size = img_02.size
img_03_size = img_02.size
img_02_size = img_02.size

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (2*img_01_size[0],2*img_01_size[1]), (250,250,250))

new_im.paste(img_01, (0,0))
new_im.paste(img_02, (img_01_size[0],0))
new_im.paste(img_03, (0,img_01_size[1]))
new_im.paste(img_04, (img_01_size[0],img_01_size[1]))

new_im.save("merged_images.png", "PNG")
```

Unsure of where to loop within pil. kindly help.

[image]

Comment: It would probably be better and simpler to only open the images in your list: `my_imgs = [ Image.open(f"{i}.png") for i in my_list]` ; thus you have a list of the images you actually want to merge, and you can write the merging part of your code using this list.

Comment: Of course, the code for the merging part depends on the total number of images you might have to merge, the way you want to position them, their size (or sizes if they don't all have the same size).

Comment: The total number of images is roughly 200 but all of same size.

Comment: The total database of images is 200 but the list contains max 30 names so the merged image is 30 all small like icons.

Comment: Yes at max 6 x 6 grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work (I haven tested it on a small sample of 5 images in a 3x2 grid). Of course, if the grid's size depends on the number of images, you'll want to replace the values for `grid_width` and `grid_height` in the code with values calculated from len(my_images):

```
from PIL import Image

with open('w.txt') as f:
    my_list =list(f)
    print(my_list)

my_images = [Image.open(f"{i.strip()}.png") for i in my_list if i.strip()]
width, height = my_images[0].size

grid_width, grid_height = 6, 6

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (grid_width * width, grid_height * height), (250,250,250))

for i, image in enumerate(my_images):
    y, x = divmod(i, grid_width)
    new_im.paste(image, (x * width, y * height))

new_im.save("merged_images.png", "PNG")
```

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1\n.png'
The list from w.txt file contains name as 1, should it be named 1.png? What to do with \n line break?

Comment: Yes your code works. I tested it with my data. How did you name the files in w.txt? It works, when i hard code list items my_list = ['1', '2']. Thanks for the help. I am accepting the answer.

Comment: I changed the code so it works with a `w.txt` file holding a number per line.

Comment: Much appreciated. This solution exactly solves the question in hand.

Comment: Whilst this code will likely work absolutely fine for the OP's question, please be aware of a couple of potential issues in the more general case. 1) It will not work correctly if the images have any transparency. 2) If your images are large or numerous, it loads all the images into memory and then creates a new canvas to paste them into which means it needs double the RAM (to hold the list as well as the canvas) whereas it could paste one image at a time. This may become an issue with multiprocessing too if all processes are squandering RAM. It's fine for this question and has my vote

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the RAM aspect afterwards; if it becomes an issue, the images could actually be loaded one by one in the last for loop instead of all in `my_images`.